# Find phone number in longtext field using mysql. return only phone number

Tags: mysql

I have a site with many pages. I am trying to create a report of all phone numbers in a longtext field type.  There is a lot of text in each field, so I don't want all of the content. Just the phone numbers.  I am trying to use the area code, 308, to Locate. I would like to start 1 position back and return 14 characters. 
This is what I was trying, but I seem to be doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Fieldname', LOCATE('Fieldname', 308)-1, 14)
FROM
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The query above doesn't error out, but it returns odd results: 
`
`
`
`
`
`
`
`
Each on their own line. Using phpmyadmin to run the query.

Comment: => `'Fieldname'` => did you mean to get a column in there instead of the _string_ `'Fieldname'` ?

Comment: I got the query above from another site. I had tried flipping the position of the two values in Locate, with no success.

Comment: Wrikken, you seem to indicate I have my syntax wrong?